# Como cambio la clase de dependiendo de su valor en C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo este formulario que me arroja dos datos "activo y desactivado, como lograr que cambien dependiendo, con la clase

```
class"label label-success y label-danger`

  <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
          <tr>
              <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PKOBJETO)
                      </td>
                              <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ESTATUS)
                      </td>                                       
         }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrias hacer seria poner una condicion dentro de tu ciclo y en base a eso agregar la clase que necesitas por otra parte podemos usar un label ya que a `DisplayFor` no se le puede agregar una clase por que solo plasma como tal el contenido y `LabelFor` plasma la etiqueta  con el contenido dentro de la etiqueta

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
     <tr>
        @if(item.ESTATUS=="Activo"){
        <td>
           @Html.LabelFor(model => item.PKOBJETO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label label-success" })
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.LabelFor(model => item.ESTATUS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label label-success" })
        </td>
        }
        else {
        <td>
           @Html.LabelFor(model => item.PKOBJETO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label-danger" })
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.LabelFor(model => item.ESTATUS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label-danger" })
        </td>
        }
     </tr>
     }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Me ha servido, gracias, apenas estoy empezando a programar en C#

Comment: @DC-Rom si te ha funcionado  alguna de las respuestas considera marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general, en razor, la mejor opción es usar el [Operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario)

Teniendo como ejemplo las clases `estaActivo` y `estaDesactivado` podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
<td class="@(item.ESTATUS=="Activo" ? "estaActivo" : "estaDesactivado")"> @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PKOBJETO) </td>
```